# How can I mount a user's existing .ssh directory into a Docker container?

Tags: docker, ssh-keys, boot2docker

I'm using boot2docker on Windows 7.  VirtualBox is mounting my Windows ~/.ssh directory from Windows (`c:\Users\Me\.ssh`) inside the boot2docker VM (`/c/Users/Me/.ssh`).

My Dockerfile is configuring an image to be used as a development environment.  It copies to the container a set of SSH keys and a config that are used for automatic deployment.  This works fine.  When the container starts up, it automatically clones a git repository within the image without prompts.

I'm now trying to use the same image but allow for the user to mount via `docker run -v ...` their own .ssh directory so they can optionally use their own SSH keys instead.  When I do that by adding in `-v /home/myself/.ssh:/home/guest/.ssh` to the command that runs the container, I get the SSH warning about the permissions being too open:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0777 for '/home/guest/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /home/guest/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I tried adding into the ENTRYPOINT script a line to `chmod -R 700 /home/guest/.ssh` but it appears that that is either ineffective or it is executed before the volume is mounted.

I also tried changing the permissions of `/home/guest/.ssh` from within the running container and was unable to do so.  I get no error when running `chmod -R 700 /home/guest/.ssh` but the permissions do not change.

I saw in another question about Docker volume permissions the suggestion that the questioner use ACLs, but I didn't know if that was a good idea, or if it would even work.

Regardless, what is the simplest way to allow a user to use their own SSH keys and SSH config inside a Docker container?

Comment: You could copy the .ssh files into a new directory and chmod them, in the startup of the shell.

Comment: So, have the Dockerfile COPY id_rsa* and config to /home/guest, for example, and in a ~/.profile copy /home/guest/id_rsa* to /home/guest/.ssh/ and avoid mounting the external .ssh volume?

Comment: Oh, no, I get it I think.  Still give the container the SSH files via a volume, but use the shell to copy them to .ssh.  Okay.  I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @Bryan Brilliant!  If it doesn't strike you as kludgy, works great for me.  Thank you.

Comment: Copied info out to an answer, so this qn doesn't show up as 'unanswered'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slightly kludgy, but you could copy the .ssh files into a new directory and chmod them, in the startup of the shell.

I.e. give the container the SSH files via a volume, but use the shell `~/.profile` to copy them to ~/.ssh.

Comment: see https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-56-volume-mounting-ssh-keys-into-a-docker-container

Comment: if you are using vscode devcontainers, you can use the `postCreateCommand` to copy and chmod the ssh files. At this point it usually makes sense to create a `postCreateCommand.sh` script and call it in the `postCreateCommand`